# VBA macros in Excel If, Then,Else?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 versions of a workbook, 1 has 4 tabs, one has 8, and one has 12. All tabs in the last one consist of the other two workbooks and the same for the second contains the first. What I need is for my macro to skip searching for the other 8/4 tabs in the earlier versions so that I do not have to click debug each time i have an old version of the workbook loading. I am VERY new to this, so any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

The error happens because the tab does not exist in certain versions of the workbook.

```
Sub TO_LOAD_OctDec()
' Macro to load data from workbook to master workbook.
'

' Open master database and prepare for transfer
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Property & Casualty\PPE\Wildfires\California Wildfires 2017\Submissions\CWF2017-MasterDatabase.xlsx"


' Focus is given to workbook to obtain correct filename.
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Sheets("Ready").Select
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

' Transfer company info
    Application.GoTo Reference:="CoInfo"
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("CoInfo").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer personal property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("PersonalP").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer commercial property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("CommercialP").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer Auto data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("Auto").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer Other Lines data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("OtherLines").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer DF personal property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("DF_Residential").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer DF commercial property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("DF_Commercial").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer DF Auto data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("DF_Auto").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer DF Other Lines data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("DF_Other").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer MM Personal Property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("MM_Personal").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer MM Commercial Property data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("MM_Commercial").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer MM Auto data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("MM_Auto").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select

' Transfer MM Other Lines data
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("MM_Other").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select



' Save and close master database
    Sheets("CoInfo").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

' TimeStamp
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Range("F11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include in your question the error you are getting and on which line you are getting it.

Comment: As an aside: Why are you maintaining 3 workbooks with duplicate data?

Comment: try `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Its not duplicate data and its difficult to get companies to use updated workbooks.

Comment: Yigit: Where would I place that code?

Comment: Also, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function to find out if a sheet exists:

```
Public Function HasSheet(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sheetNameUcase As String
    sheetNameUcase = UCase(SheetName)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If UCase(Sheets.Item(i).Name) = sheetNameUcase Then
            HasSheet = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    HasSheet = False
End Function
```

Then use it like in this example:

```
' Transfer DF Auto data
If HasSheet("Data") Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Range("DF_Auto").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
End If
```

Also, avoid using `On Error Resume Next`. Essentially it disables all error trapping. It should be treated like an atomic bomb.